# Regarding a 3-Sum algorithm, how is the number of array accesses calculated (1/2 N^3), and how is the order of growth calculated (N^3)?

Tags: java, algorithm

[image: Relevant lecture slide]

I understand how the value 1/6 N^3 is found through combinatorics, but I thought this represented the number of array accesses. This slide says that the actual number is 1/2 N^3. I understand that we are only counting array accesses for the program and that each array access is 1 time unit, but I'm not clear on tilde notation, and how that removes the 1/2 from the value for the order of growth. Could anyone explain this please?

Comment: *1/6 N³* is the number of times the "inner loop" iterates. Since that code has 3 array accesses, you multiply by *3* and get *1/2 N³*. --- Order of Growth, aka [Big-O](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Big_O_notation), eliminates constant factors, so it is just _O(N³)_

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `if` statement is executed `1/6*N^3` times. Each call of this `if` statement leads to 3 array accesses: a[i], a[j], a[k]. So we get:

```
(1/6*N^3) * 3 = 1/2*N^3
```